# unable to access FormGroup from my service in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

i am trying to access "FromGroup" value(declared as public) from my service, in my component class.
but i am getting undefined, where as rest of other private values i could able to access. please clarify.

### workflost.service.ts

```
@Injectable()

export class UnderstandWorkflowService implements CanActivate{
public contactDetails: FormGroup;
private workflow=[];
private steps=[];
private currentStep:string="";
}
```

### contact.component.ts

```
export class ContactComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
contactDetails: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.understandService.contactDetails){
      this.contactDetails = this.understandService.contactDetails;
    }
  }
}
```

when i try to debug from my contact.component.ts - ngOnInit function i could able to see all private properties of my above service but i couldn't able to access or get contactDetails:FromGroup, it showing as undefined.
anybody can help on this ?

Comment: where the value is defined? i dnt see any value assigned to it

Comment: See in the service I defined as public(contactDetails), and I try to access from my below component...